# Use jQuery to get the file input's selected filename with actual full path

Tags: javascript, jquery, filepath, realpath

I used this:

```
$('input[type=file]').val()
```

to get the full file path selected, but it returned the fakepath, as in "C:\fakepath\filename.jpg". The "fakepath" part was actually there - not sure if it's supposed to be, but this is my first time working on webapp.

How can I just get the full file path (c:\Phone\DCIM\Camera\filename.jpg)?

As I want to call out the file when user click on the link.

Comment: You can't due to security restriction.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get full path of selected file on change of <input type=‘file’> using javascript, jquery-ajax?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15201071/how-to-get-full-path-of-selected-file-on-change-of-input-type-file-using-jav)

Answer (score 2):

Browser can never provide the full path for a file because of security issues.